# how to store facebook friends to DB (newbie)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

i'm creating a facebook-app for university project and i'm trying to store all my friends in the DB.
By using the API-syntax "me/friends" i get a facebook-respond looking like this:

```
{"data"=>[{"name"=>"Albert Einstein", "id"=>"11111111"}, {"name"=>"Max Mustermann", "id"=>"222222222"}, {"name"=>"Just Another Name", "id"=>"333333333"}]}
```

I believe its a json-object, but i'm not sure.

Question: How can i save the data, i need a DB with all the User-IDs of my friends.

Thx!

Edit:

Hey, this is what i have searched for. But i still get an error and don't know why. 
My code:

```
def insert_1
fb_friends = rest_graph.get('me/friends')
fb_friends[:data].each do |f|
  @friend = Model.new(:name => f["name"] )
  @friend.save
end
end
```

I get an Heroku error (We're sorry, but something went wrong.)

Comment: Remember to accept (check) an answer which solves your problem!

Answer (score 6):

You have two options -

**Option 1-**

You can create a friends table which will belong to users table. If a user has 200 friends, it will create 200 entries in friends table all belonging to the user via has_many-belongs_to relationship. For storing data, you just have to iterate over facebook friends hash and then save each of them separately
**Pros** : You can search for any friend separately.
**Cons** : There will be so many of friend entries. Saving them will take time, if somebody has many friends(say 500-700). Repeating entries will be created for mutual friends.

**Options 2**

You can add a friends column in your users table and declare this in your user.rb

```
serialize :friends
```

This way, you just have to pass a hash object to friends attribute of user table, and rails will save that in yaml format for you. When you will do @user.friends, rails will again convert that yaml formatted data to hash object and return it. 
**Pros** : There will be only one query to save all users. You can iterate through this hash to show list of all friends.
**Cons** : You can't update them separately, you will update all together. Not good if you want to store some other information in relation to user's friends.

**Update**

as per your code example above

```
  fb_friends = #your logic to get data as shown above.
  fb_friends[:data].each do |f|
    @friend = Friend.new(:name => f["name"],:fb_user_id => f["id"] )#creating Friend model obj.
    @friend.save
  end
```

Comment: thx rtdp for the fast answer. i want to do it like option 1. but i need only the "friends" table not a second. my idea is to have no duplicate entries by using "validates uniqueness". My problem is exactly the iteration through the json-"hash" of facebook. I think I have to use an each-block? Or do i have to convert the json to an other format before saving to DB? Can you give me en example code? Sorry, i'm really new in ruby on rails.

Comment: updated my answer for code example. you this solved the prob, then accept this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work